# Opening notification with ADB and notification ID on Android

Tags: adb, notifications

I am trying to open a notification on my Android device using ADB and the notification ID, but I am getting the following error message:

`Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] dat=24 } Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] dat=24 flg=0x10000000 }`

I have used the following command to try to open the notification:

`adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.DEFAULT -d 24`

I am sure that I have entered the correct notification ID and that the app that sent the notification is installed on my device. What could be the cause of this error and how can I fix it?

I have tried the following steps to troubleshoot the issue, but I am still getting the error message:

I have checked to make sure that I have entered the correct notification ID. I have used the adb shell dumpsys notification command to get a list of open notification IDs and made sure that the ID I have entered is valid.

I have made sure that the app that sent the notification is installed on my device.

Comment: I don't think ADB can interact with notifications directly, but at least the command on the question won't work because `am` (Activity Manager) is for opening an activity.

Comment: Also posted on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74996481/2821954